# Suspend does not work with gnome and gdm3 on 17.04

Tags: gnome, suspend, lightdm, 17.04, gdm

After upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 and switch to gnome-desktop and gd3m the suspend does not work anymore. When try to suspend a black screen is displayed but in a fee seconds (1-2s) the login screen appear again, but in this case the login screen does not work because when type the password and hit enter the login screen appear again, without login in the desktop. Then at this point is needed restart. The following is the log that I found in syslog when try to suspend:

```
May  4 14:49:30 Rafael-PC NetworkManager[1053]: <info>  [1493923770.4435] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May  4 14:49:30 Rafael-PC NetworkManager[1053]: <info>  [1493923770.4435] manager: sleeping...
May  4 14:49:30 Rafael-PC NetworkManager[1053]: <info>  [1493923770.4438] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
May  4 14:49:30 Rafael-PC gnome-shell[2764]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
May  4 14:49:30 Rafael-PC NetworkManager[1053]: <info>  [1493923770.4474] device (ttyACM0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
May  4 14:49:30 Rafael-PC NetworkManager[1053]: <info>  [1493923770.4476] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
May  4 14:49:30 Rafael-PC wpa_supplicant[1715]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
May  4 14:49:30 Rafael-PC wpa_supplicant[1715]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Unit entered failed state.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: (EE)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: Fatal server error:
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: (EE) systemd-logind disappeared (stopped/restarted?)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: (EE)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: (EE)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]:  for help.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: (EE)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: (EE)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: Fatal server error:
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: (EE) systemd-logind disappeared (stopped/restarted?)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: (EE)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: (EE)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]:  for help.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2591]: (EE)
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
May  4 14:49:32 Rafael-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2945]: (EE) systemd-logind: ReleaseControl failed: You are not in control of this session
```

Performed tests:

- [FAIL] Reinstalling the gdm3 with purge but nothing, suspend does not works.
- [FAIL] Reinstall Nvidia drivers and test with multiple versions
- [FAIL] Testing with X.Org Nouveau Display driver
- [FAIL] apt-get upgrade
- [OK] Switching the display manager to lightdm and the suspend works fine.

At this point the only solution that I found is switch to lightdm display manager, but for me is not a real solution. Please any suggestion or help?

Comment: when I did `systemctl suspend` on the configuration you said. It worked for me. sure it turned the display off and then for a short second it turned back on to show lockscreen but then it suspended. How did you suspend again?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably switch to lightdm.

I also had problems with gdm in Ubuntu 17.04 mainly about logging in.
I had to go to recovery mode and use dpkg to change it back to lightdm.

It may be because the transition from unity to gnome-shell is only partial in ubuntu 17.04.